# vsftpd server allow anonymous to upload files and nothing else

Tags: linux, ftp, anonymous

Trying to let anonymous users login and upload files to a directory "/srv/ftp/dropbox" but not see or download anything.

Can login as anonymous but when I try and upload a file with the following command I get these error's.

```
put /home/username/TestFTP /srv/ftp/dropbox/TestFTP  
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||30094|).  
553 Could not create file.
```

The "/etc/vsftpd.conf" file has this in it, If its not on list its commented out most likely.

```
write_enable=YES  
dirmessage_enable=YES  
nopriv_user=ftpsecure  
local_enable=YES  
chroot_local_user=YES  
chroot_list_enable=NO  
allow_writeable_chroot=YES  
anonymous_enable=YES  
anon_world_readable_only=YES  
anon_upload_enable=YES  
chown_uploads=YES  
chown_username=username  
anon_root=/srv/ftp/dropbox  
syslog_enable=YES  
log_ftp_protocol=YES  
xferlog_enable=YES  
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log  
connect_from_port_20=YES  
ssl_enable=NO  
userllist_deny=NO  
userlist_enable=YES  
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allow_users
```

Permissions on the directories are

```
srv = drwxr-xr-x  
ftp = drwxr-xr-x  
dropbox = drwx-wx---
```

Ownership of the 3 folders is set to root right now

The OS i am running is openSUSE 12.2 for more information.

Comment: please provide ownership information for the folders

Comment: Just updated it, still having problems.

Comment: You seem to have made yourself two Stack Exchange accounts. You should [have them merged](http://serverfault.com/help/user-merge). This will let you edit your own question without having to get approval.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to upload to `/srv/ftp/dropbox/srv/ftp/dropbox/TestFTP`

try just

```
put /home/username/TestFTP
```

Comment: Still same error

Answer (score 0):

Also check SELinux policies and variables, particularly the following one: 
`allow_ftpd_anon_write`

Comment: Was trying this but don't think it is a option for the version i am using or i am missing something.

Comment: What OS are you using?